# How to curl with json postfields?

Tags: php, json, paypal

Here's my code:

```
$pp = curl_init();
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans");
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 6);
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "page_size=3&status=ALL&page=1&total_required=yes");
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token"
));

$result_pp = curl_exec($pp);
echo $result_pp;
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"The request JSON is not well formed.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"b742c35fe6e0e"}
```

This is the documentation link:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/#billing-plans_list
```

Basically just trying to pull a list of all my PayPal subscriptions, but it looks like I'm not sending something in JSON correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending a `POST` request, the API believes you are attempting to [create a billing plan](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/#billing-plans), and that being the case, your post data is expected to be in json form - which it is not.

According to the docs, to [list your plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/#billing-plans_list),  the request type should be `GET`.  So you need to add your params in the url:

```
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans?page_size=3&status=ALL&page=1&total_required=yes");
```

And remove these two lines:

```
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($pp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "page_size=3&status=ALL&page=1&total_required=yes");
```

It's important to understand that many RESTful APIs use the request types to differentiate between actions on the same endpoint. `PATCH`, `POST`, `PUT`, `GET` and `DELETE` requests may all have different meanings depending on the API.